# Why can't Linux display/run lua code on my Chromebook in terminal?

Tags: linux, lua, debian, love2d, chromebook

I'm desperately trying to open a game using *Love2d* and the following error occurs when I insert `love /path/to/my/proyect/`on my Chromebook terminal.

```
Error

boot.lua:577: Cannot load game at path '/home/path/to/PROYECTOS/'.
Make sure a folder exists at the specified path.`

Traceback

[C]: in function 'error'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Can anyone help me please understand what is going wrong pls? Oh, and by the way. Yes, I have putted a folder inside `PROYECTOS` which is the one where the `main.lua` script (my game) is stored. I am gonna provide photos of how I did setup my Chromebook since it could be the underlying problem.

**Hope this image clarifies the issue:**

[image: 1]

-In the image it can be seen  the folder `PROYECTOS`, in which there is another folder where the *main.lua* thing is stored on known as `1.PONG`

- WHAT I DID IN REGARD TO THE PROBLEM

I have tried running the Lua file based on Love2D's website ["Getting Started"](https://love2d.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and provide me the error shown on previous paragraph. Due to this, I have been searching other forums in case the solution was been given to my problem. Unfortunately, the majority of those issues were pointed up straight to Windows systems and not Linux Systems. What I expected was that the code as itself run and displays as a form of a image showcasing the code I had input in. However, I was greeted upon a error within no apparent reason. And I put a folder inside `PROYECTOS`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Getting Started](https://love2d.org/wiki/Getting_Started) page states:

> **Running Games**
> LÖVE can load a game in two ways:
>
> - From a folder that contains a main.lua file.
> - From a .love file that has a main.lua file in the top-most directory level (aka root)

So if your `1.PONG` directory contains your `main.lua` file, then you need to run:

```
love /path/to/PROYECTOS/1.PONG/
```

with `/path/to` adjusted accordingly.

Basically, pass the path of the directory that *contains* your `main.lua` file to the `love` executable.

Comment: The thing is that even when input the right command provides me the same error as I had just encountered previously in the one cited in the first paragraph and I had just executed the same steps as you told me to do. I don't know if the problem may relie on the distribution of the folder, for instance. Since I am using a chromebook maybe when I place the folder on a differect section (Ej: DESCARGAS, ARCHIVOS DE LINUX as it can be depicted on the photos) may had to something with it to the error to happen. Anyway, I am gonna show the photo via a link of the error I have: https://ibb.co/rpDTYv9

Comment: I know this question might sound dumb, but the thing is that the main.lua inside 1.PONG is basically a set of commands representing the "Hello World" thing. To understand better what I am trying to tell. See the photo here: https://ibb.co/gWkJyJN

Comment: @OliverMolinaMayor Unless you literally have a directory structure with the directories `path` and `to` from root, then of course `love /path/to/PROYECTOS/1.PONG/` will not work. It is just an example path. You need to figure out the actual path for the directory that contains your `main.lua` file. From your home directory, try locating this directory using tools like `ls`, `cd`, and `pwd`. If you are completely confused, you probably need a tutorial on basic Unix filesystem navigation. Try reading something [like this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/beginner-linux-navigation-manual).

Comment: And depending on how you are trying to access these files, you may need to read ["Sharing files to Linux"](https://chromeos.dev/en/linux/setup#sharing-files-to-linux).

Comment: ohhhh I see what you mean now. I thought it was the command I needed to use in order to run the lua proyect, but in reality it was the example path to it. Thanks for informing me about this. I was a bit confused regarding why the command I had just inputted coulnt run and the reason was because I was always inputting the example path and not the real path. That is some GREAT help, especially when there isn't that amount of information of the necessary procedures to undertake in order to run a command properly. Overall, thanks for claryfing me about this misconception.

Comment: I will ask you more help if I get stuck again in some of your mentioned steps.